# Select one product WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, woocommerce, archive

I am trying to create a div that shows up once I hover over an article on the archive-product.php page in WooCommerce.

Well the hovering and showing up of a div is working perfectly, but once I hover over ONE product, all divs are showing up for all the different products on the same page.

How can I make sure only the div specified with the information of the product I am hovering currently is showing up instead of all the windows.

Here is what I go so far:

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-images">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

</a>
        <?php
        /** this piece of code is specially ment for the pop-up to show
        *
        * @hooked will be specified later
        * @hooked will be specified later
        */
        ?>
<div class="popup-product-custom" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 75%; margin-left: 250px; z-index: 2147483647; background-color: #FFFFFF;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button-in-popup">This is a test button</a></div>


<div class="product-details">

    <div class="product-details-container">

        <h3 class="product-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <div class="clearfix">

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'Custom_edits_product_loop_bottom1' );
    do_action( 'Custom_edits_product_loop_bottom2' );
    do_action( 'Custom_edits_product_loop_bottom3' );
?>
```

And here the jQuery which works on it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".popup-product-custom").hide();

jQuery(".post-type-archive-product .product-type-simple, .archive.tax-product-cat .product-type-simple").hover(function() {
    jQuery(".popup-product-custom").slideToggle();
});
```

});

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, already figured out a good working solution.
Here are my jQuery changes:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//jQuery(this).children(".popup-product-custom").hide();

jQuery(".post-type-archive-product .product-type-simple, .archive.tax-product-cat .product-type-simple").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).children(".popup-product-custom").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

I added the code in the header of this particular WooCommerce page, because jQuery was malfunctioning some other custom plug-ins out of WooCommerce inside WordPress.

Also added the following CSS code:

```
.post-type-archive-product .popup-product-custom {display: none;}
```

and

```
.archive.tax-product_cat .popup-product-custom {display: none;}
```

This seems to solve my problem :)